Pre-fill a collection with information from a selector that receives TMDB data. Is this possible? PAYLOAD 3.0
I have a question, I work with payload 3.0.
I created a Movie collection, in this collection, I have a title, a date, a language etc. In this Movie collection, I have a selector that receives movie titles from an external api with TMDB. What I want to know is is it possible by clicking on a movie in the selector, to pre-fill my Movie collection with the movie information.
Thank you so much
I don't know if it's possible,
I couldn't find it on the internet ..
